# JUnit test fails due to different line separators in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, junit

When running a JUnit test on a String the test fails. As you can see IntelliJ tells us that "Contents have difference only in line separators" So the test is expecting the string to have CRLF but is getting LF. Now, as someone who's never encountered line separation as an issue and someone who has looked at other answers on Stackoverflow and elsewhere to no avail, it seems like I need to somehow change my line separation to CRLF. Now I have looked here in IntelliJ: Settings -> Code Style -> Line Separation. But I can't find the keywords "CRLF" and "LF" here. Only Windows, Unix, Mac etc. So I don't really know if I should change anything there? I also tested these commands in the cmd: `git config core.autocrlf false` Which didn't effect it in any way.  There was an answer that explained how to change from CRLF to LF, which is the opposite of what I wanna do. And the autocrlf was set to true before I changed it. So it doesn't seem to have mattered.

What should I do? How do I change my line separation from LF to CRLF?

I interpreted CRLF to be \r\n and therefore picked the 3rd option in the dropdown menu (Second image) but it did not solve it.

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Line separator options:
[image: Line separator]

Comment: CRLF is Windows line separators. Make sure to Reformat the code in the project so that the strings in the files are updated. You may want to change your test code so that it loads the resources and handles the line separators independently on the OS.